# Variable conventions in Python __init__ class method

Tags: python, class, self

If I have a class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

        self.arg3 = self.arg1 + self.arg2
```

Is there a convention in terms of which vars to use to calculate `arg3`? Can I do this instead?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

        self.arg3 = arg1 + arg2
```

Is one faster than the other, is there some agreed-upon practice, or does it not really matter?

Comment: I wouldn't do either - make `arg3` a *property* that's calculated based on `arg1` and `arg2`, otherwise it can get out of sync.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but I would prefer the parameters where applicable.

Comment: Whether `arg3` should be a property is really beyond the scope of the question: its value may or may not need to change if the value of `self.arg1` or `self.arg2` changes.

Comment: Yes I'm seeing comments regarding turning ```arg3``` into a property. I'm not that experienced in coding and I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Note, however, that if `arg1` or `arg2` is a property, then `self.arg3 = self.arg1 + self.arg2` and `self.arg3 = arg1 + arg2` don't necessarily do the same thing.

Comment: AFAIK v2 is faster, because python interpreter requires extra time to access class attr `self.arg1`(v1). Smbd, please, correct me, if I'm wrong

Comment: @Yurii that's probably technically true, but it's the kind of micro-optimization that doesn't matter. But it's an instance attr, not a class attr.

Comment: If you're worried about the amount of time it takes to access `self.arg1` vs. `arg1`, you should be using a more performant language than python.